# How to set columns in a JTextArea to show text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm using (in a JPanel with GridLayout) some JTextAreas (with Editable=false) to show some text after a query to a database XML.

```
JTextArea obj = new JTextArea();
obj.setColumns(37);
obj.setText(r.getProtocolloList().get(i).getOggetto());
```

The problem is that this text can be quite long and it is showed all in a single line so that the user has to scroll the horizontal JScrollPane to read the rest. 
I thought that setting the columns the line would be restricted so that the text would be showed in different lines. But nothing happens.
Is there a way to get that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `setLineWrap();` method:

```
obj.setLineWrap(true);
```